# Completing CSS transform when unhover

Tags: css, hover, transform, transition

```
.example:hover {
  transform: skew(30deg,20deg);
  transition: all 10s ease-in-out;
}
```

If I hover the element it starts scewing for 10 seconds. But if I unhover before 10 seconds it stops scewing.

Is there a way to unhover the element and still have it complete the skew for the full 10 seconds?

In other words, hover the element once and it will scew for 10 seconds, regardless if you unhover or not.

Comment: Would it be a solution to include the reverse effect (i.e. back to normal) on unhover? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NDmwj/ (note I reduced the time to 3 sec to make testing go quicker)

Comment: I need it to continue scewing in the same direction on unhover. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in pure CSS; you'll probably need Javascript for that, like bboy says. I'm curious if any CSS-only solutions turn up though.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the jquery `hover` and `css`

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/NPnBz/1/

---

update: you might want to add the proper prefixes on transform

read here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Comment: After skewing for 10 seconds is done, I need it instantly back to its original state (so hovering the element again would scew it for another 10 seconds and so on).

Comment: mmm jquery `hover` doesn't have a callback, so we will need to use something like `animate`